# ‘Vanity’ v ‘Meaningless’ v ‘Futile’ in Ecclesiastes

Tags: translation-philosophy, ecclesiastes

The book of Ecclesiastes repeats the phrase “vanity of vanities”, or similar, many times in some translations, including ESV.  However, in some other translations, it is rendered “meaningless, meaningless” (eg, NIV) or “futile, futile” (eg, NET).

Eg, the very second verse of Ecclesiastes says:

> Vanity of vanities, says the Preacher, vanity of vanities! All is vanity.

(Ecc 1:2 ESV)

What word is used in the original language (Hebrew?) and why is it translated so differently?  What is the most accurate translation?

(I can see that “meaningless” and “futile” are somewhat similar, but “vanity” seems quite different to me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a matter of realising how the meaning of English words can change in time. This is very relevant when people are looking at the Authorised Version of 1611. In this case, "vanity" used to have a broader meaning which covers the other two renderings.

The root is the Latin VANUS, in my Latin dictionary as "empty, void, vain, idle, worthless, meaningless". Leading to VANITAS; "emptiness, worthlessness, unreality, boasting, ostentation".

The definition of "vanity" in my Concise Oxford Dictionary begins "Futility, unsubstantiality, unreality, emptiness, unsubstantial or unreal thing." Only further down the entry do we get "empty pride, conceit, based on personal attainments or attractions or qualities".

We need to be aware of the frst half of that definition when we are reading Bunyan's account of Vanity Fair.

So the short answer to your question is that "vanity" means or at least used to mean the same thing as the other two.

Comment: Thank you, that's quite enlightening.  I was expecting that the answer might be found with a better understanding of Hebrew, but it turns out that what I actually needed was a better understanding of English.  How ironic.

Comment: You might add that Isaiah 45:18 translates the Hebrew word "tohu" as "vain": "*… he created [the Earth] not in vain, he formed it to be inhabited …*".
This is the same Hebrew word that appears in Genesis 1:2, commonly translated as "without form", or "waste".